# Difficulties with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I am having difficulties to draw the following circuit in `circuitikz`:

Especially when it comes to drawing R1 and R2 branched to op amp.+

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide the code for the rest of the diagram and please correct your subject line so this question is easier for others to find.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have done so far!

Answer (score 3):

The terminals of `opamp` can be accessed using `opamp.+`, `opamp.-` and `opamp.out`. The network nodes can also be named while drawing the resistors using `node` option. Then just connecting these named nodes finishes the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}\draw
(1.5,0) node [op amp] (opamp) {}
(-3,-4)node[ground]{} to[sV] ++(0,2) to[R,a=$2\,k\Omega$, l=$R_1$] ++(3,0)node(i1){} to[R,a=$1\,k\Omega$, l=$R_2$] ++(3,0)node(i2){}
(-3,2)node[ground]{} to[R,a=$2\,k\Omega$, l=$R_4$] ++(3,0)node(i3){} to[R,a=$2\,k\Omega$, l=$R_3$] ++(3,0) node(i4){}
(i1.center) to[short,*-] (i1.center|-opamp.+) -- (opamp.+)
(i3.center) to[short,*-] (i3.center|-opamp.-) -- (opamp.-)
(i4.center) to[short,-*] (i4.center|-opamp.out) to[R,a=$1\,k\Omega$, l=$R_5$,-*](i2.center) to[R,european,l=load] ++(0,-2)node[ground]{}
(i4.center|-opamp.out) -- (opamp.out)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

a small variation of nice [nidhin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370674/difficulties-with-circuitikz/463908#463908) answer:

- for units are used `siunitx` syntax
- for auxiliary coordinates are used `coordinate` and not `node`
- drawing is different organised

  ```
  \documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
  % drawn from bottom to top
  % lower branch
  \draw  node [ground]{}
          to  [sV]                        ++ (0,2)
          to  [R, a=2<\kilo\ohm>,l=$R_1$] ++ (3,0)    coordinate (n1)
          to  [R, a=1<\kilo\ohm>,l=$R_2$] ++ (3,0)    coordinate (n2)
          to  [R, l=load]                 ++ (0,-2)
         node [ground]{}
  % operational amplifier branch
  (n1)    to  [short,*-]                  ++ (0,1.5)
         node [op amp, anchor=+] (A) {}
  (A.out) to  [short,-*]              (A.out -| n2)
          to  [R, a=1<\kilo\ohm>,l=$R_5$,-*]   (n2)
  (A.-)   to  [short,-*]                  ++ (0,1.5)  coordinate (n3)
  % upper branch
          to  [R, l=2<\kilo\ohm>,a=$R_4$] ++ (-3,0)
         node [ground]{}
  (n3)    to  [R, a=2<\kilo\ohm>,l=$R_3$] ++ (3,0)
          to  (A.out -|n2)
          ;
  \end{circuitikz}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]