# connect line to an unknown coordinate TIKZ

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

Is it possible to connect the source of M0 to a line defined in the beginning of the code?

```
\path (0,0) coordinate (GND); %% the line below
```

the transistor: I don't know exactly the coordinates of the drain and source

```
\draw   (nC15) ++(1,0) node[nmos,anchor=gate,scale=1.5](M0){}
        (M0.drain) node[above right]{$M_0$}  ;
```

Comment: please add a complete and compileable minimum example

Comment: Can you please show us a short compilable tex code what you have tried so far? As with your previous question, your question doesn't explain exactly what you want. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing (and wanting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name `node` or `coordinate` and then use those names to draw lines. See the code below. I have defined a node `(gnd)` at `(0,0)` and later, the connection is made from `nmos` source terminal to `(gnd)`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\node[ground] (gnd) at (0,0){}; % node (gnd) at (0,0)
\draw   (2,4) ++(1,0) node[nmos,anchor=gate,scale=1.5](M0){}
        (M0.drain) node[above right]{$M_0$}  ; 
\draw (M0.source) |- (gnd); % draw from source to gnd
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to get a circle(a connection point) at the intersection of the source and the gnd line?

Comment: @tairebit I have not defined a ground line. I defined a point `gnd` and drew connection to that point. But yes. One can draw a gnd line and It is possible to have connection point. See this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463908/28557)